# Usage of areas in .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, .net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Core application. In this application I'm using areas. I have multiple areas now: Administrator (for website maintenance), Identity  (for identity razor pages) and Public (for visitors).

I like those areas, but I dont' like the fact that I need my visitors url's look like: https://localhost:5001/Public/Home and https://localhost:5001/Public/Catalogue, etc.

I more like urls like https://localhost:5001/Home and https://localhost:5000/Catalogue etc.

Is there any possibility, where I can use areas, except for the visitor part of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not recommend to get rid of "area name" in the url, because the routing will not work properly when you have similar page names in different areas! e.g. if you have two areas "public" and "private" and both contains pages with similar name "Index" most probably you will see an error that there is multiple pages using the same route, and thats why areas are exists.

back to your issue, if you are using razor pages you may add the route template directly to the top of razor page:

```
@page "/catalog"
```

or if you have parameters:

```
@page "{id}"
@Url.Page("/catalog")
```

if you are using MVC, then you may use attribute routing and keep AreaPrefix empty:

```
[RouteArea("Public", AreaPrefix = "")]
[RoutePrefix("catalog")]
public class CatalogsController : Controller
```

you can read more about routing in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2